# Swift - Issue with buttonWithType and as

Tags: swift

```
var view: MKPinAnnotationView
view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton.buttonWithType(.DetailDisclosure) as! UIView
```

I am new to swift. While I was following the online tutorial (https://www.raywenderlich.com/90971/introduction-mapkit-swift-tutorial), the second line of the above code gives me following issue;

1. `buttonWithType` was not recognized. Therefore I used type `buttonType: UIButtonType` but it still gives me an error
2. In the same line of code `as!`  generates an error.

Comment: The code in the linked tutorial is written in Swift 2. If you are using Swift 3 you need to convert the code to the new syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The Syntax is changed in swift 3 you can use

```
view.rightCalloutAccessoryView  = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
```

and as **UIButton** class inherits from **UIView** class so you don't need to force cast(**as!**) it into a UIView.

Hope it helps!